# What is the most common way to notate dominant chords with a sharp fifth?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

Is just adding #5 a common practice? As in:

> D Gb Bb C E G = D11#5

I've seen it also as D11+. Is there a more conventional way to notate this?

Comment: When in the key of D, you won't get Gb, it must be F# - it's in the key signature. To get a #5, you sharpen the 5th - which is A, so A#, not Bb. + or aug. or # are the common ways to indicate a note one semitone higher than it normally is.(or even a natural sign if the note is a flat).( Or even an x if the note is already a #).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the chord were a simple triad - D F# A# - then this would be called D Aug (augumented). Adding the C would make it DAug7, adding the E would make it DAug9, and adding the G would make it DAug11. Sometimes the plus sign is used instead of Aug, so calling this D+11 (but not D11+) would be possible. Unfortunately, D+11 tends to give the impression that this is a D chord with an added 11th (but not 7th or 9th), so DAug11 would seem to be best.

Comment: Nice answer. In the D+11 case, you could also put the 11 in superscript, to avoid the +11 confusion.